# Why won't my columns align properly?

Tags: css, html

I want to have two columns on the bottom of this webpage I'm making, but they're coming out on top of each other instead of next to each other.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</style>
<style type="text/css">
@import url("adobeIndex.css");
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="banner">Content for  id "banner" Goes Here</div>
<div id="left-text">Content for  id "left-text" Goes Here</div>
<div id="1-left-column">Content for  id "1-left-column" Goes Here </div>
<div id="1-right-column"> Content for id "1-right-column" Goes Here</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#container {
width:968px;
background: #00F;
margin:auto;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
overflow:hidden;
 }

#left-text {
 width:300px;
 height:400px;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}

#1-left-column, #1-right-column {
width: 464px;
float: left;
}
#1-right-column {
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to add "HTML5" and "CSS" to your title. Stack Overflow automatically adds tags to the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't start your id names with numbers, use `left-column` and `right-column` or `one-left-column` and `one-right-column` instead

Comment: That's really all there is to it, see an example fiddle [over here](http://jsfiddle.net/rEEQA/).

Comment: Wow, the resources I've read over the last year never told me that.  Thanks!

Comment: That's what awesome communities are for, reducing the growing pains! If this answer is complete enough for you, please mark it as correct so the community knows it's been answered.